# StackOverflowError in databinding while trying to migrate Gradle plugin from 3.5.1 to 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

My goal is to migrate android gradle plugin from 3.5.1 to 3.5.2.

However, once I do that the build fails with the following error:

```
error: cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:209)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.resolveListeners(Expr.java:211)
```

It clearly states that it has something to do with databinding, but the stacktrace is really poor. I've tried to apply additional compiler args to get some other insights with no luck.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like AGP 3.5.2 fails once you invoke `ObservableField.get()` inside your xml files. Please see [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144604674#comment3) to similar problem at Google Issues Tracker.

You can try to just remove `.get()` usages from your codebase which is completely safe.

**Edit:**
If you're using LiveData, make sure you're not using `.getValue()` in any of your XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this warning on AGP 3.4.2:

> Do not explicitly call 'get()' on ObservableFields or 'getValue()' on
>   LiveData in an expression. This support will be removed soon.

It seems that this support has been removed in AGP 3.5.2 without a mention on [changelog](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-5-0).